# Subtração de Data e retornar valor positivo SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde, estou tentando montar uma Query em que faço a subtração de duas datas para me retornar o valor em dias, porém preciso somente dos dias que retornaram positivo, executei a Query que montei mas não teve retorno

```
DECLARE @POSITIVO INT

SELECT @POSITIVO = DATEDIFF(DAY, Contas_Receber.PagamentoData, Contas_Receber.Vencimento) from Contas_Receber WHERE @POSITIVO > 0
```

Me da o resultado de Comandos concluídos com êxito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber se o resultado será positivo a segunda data deve ser maior que a primeira:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, cr.PagamentoData, cr.Vencimento)
  FROM Contas_Receber cr
 WHERE cr.vencimento > cr.pagamentodata
```

Comment: Cara, valeu, funcionou perfeitamente.